# gpu driver issue flutter / android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-virtual-device

I was wondering if there is any other way to run the AVD ? im trying to run in with android studio ( to start some flutter course) but i cant open it at all i was having some HAXM problems first but seems to be fixed ... now when i press the .> icon in AVD manager from android studio i get this GPU driver issue .. i understand it prob about some driver ofc (which i think is because i have no video card installed in my computer or bettter said im only using onboard video card ) please if someone could help me or tell me if there is another way to open the AVD android phone screen, -i have uploaded  a picture from the error here i hope it appears in the question -

-thx

[gpu error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiLZF.png)

Comment: What GPU do you have?

Comment: intel g33/g31 express chipset family

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible update your graphics driver. You are using a default driver that Windows installs for you.

Or you can use [Geny Motion](https://www.genymotion.com/download/), a lightweight Android virtual device.